# Присвоить значение глобальной переменной в потоке java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я считываю с файла матрицу чисел. Я должен найти максимальное значение каждой строки, и для каждого поиска
надо открыть поток. Я создал пустой массив и присваиваю i элементу значение в потоке. Но когда вывожу в конце, при выводе на экран, эти числа все так же равны 0. Я так полагаю это из-за того, что вывод производится в то время, как потоки еще работают, а потому присваивания не происходит. Как мне заставить поток с выводом ждать, пока завершатся потоки подсчета максимального значения?

```
        String input = io.read(); // считаная с файла строка с матрицей
        String[] rows = input.split(System.lineSeparator());
        int[] maxOfEachRow = new int[rows.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            int finalI = i;
            new Thread() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int max = 0;
                    String[] numbers = rows[finalI].trim().split(" ");
                    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]) > max) {
                            max = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
                            try {
                                sleep(1);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    maxOfEachRow[finalI] = max;
                }
            }.start();
        }

        for (int max : maxOfEachRow) {
            System.out.println(max);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1.

использовать такой код

```
myThread_turn = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
     /// Здесь вычисления
    }
});
myThread_turn.start(); // запускаем
try {
    myThread_turn.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
/// Здесь вывод результата
```

Или выводить результат в потоке

```
 new Thread() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
       int max = 0;
       String[] numbers = rows[finalI].trim().split(" ");
       for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
           if (Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]) > max) {
                max = Integer.parseInt(numbers[j]);
                try {
                      sleep(1);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 }
            }
            maxOfEachRow[finalI] = max;
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 for (int max : maxOfEachRow) {
                      System.out.println(max);
                }
                }
            });
            }
        }.start();
```